# как на python получить лист процессов запущенных в windows

Tags: python, windows

и так, мне нужно получить и вывести (например print) лист процессов, я знаю что есть команда tasklist, и можно сделать так os.system('tasklist'), но он выведет другую инфу по типу Имя сессии, № сеанса, память, а мне нужно только Имя образа и больше ничего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import psutil
print([p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()])
```

Comment: как вывести каждый процесс в столбик? ну в плане каждый процесс в новой строчке, примерно так
System
Registry
winlogon.exe
smss.exe
svchost.exe
fontdrivhost.exe
csrss.ex
chrome.ex
winint.exe
и тд

Comment: import psutil
print('\n'.join([p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()]))